# Convert LinearLayout to ConstraintLayout issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to convert a horizontal `LinearLayout` that has 4 buttons of the same size to a `ConstraintLayout`.
The problem is that when I set one or more buttons to `android:visibility="gone"` in the `LinearLayout` the remaining buttons are resized to take the entire space (all will be the same size) and in the `ConstraintLayout` the buttons are removed, but still take the space.

**EDIT:** According to the app state, different buttons will be visible.

What do I need to change so the `ConstraintLayout` will behave like the `LinearLayout`?

**EDIT:** I found a mistake in the ConstraintLayout (constraint references) so I updated it and the images (the problem still exists).

`LinearLayout` xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:text="B1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:text="B2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:text="B3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:text="B4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:** `ConstraintLayout` xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:text="B1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/b2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:text="B2"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/b1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/b3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:text="B3"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/b2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/b4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:text="B4"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/b3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: LinearLayout vs ConstraintLayout]
[image: ConstraintLayout blueprint]

Comment: why do you want to replace linear layout if it is working correctly? is it slow? does it eat a lot of memory?

Comment: I have a complex layout structure so I am converting it to a constraint layout. This is one part that I did not managed to convert.

Comment: I know that I can embed the linear layout inside the constrain layout, but would like to avoid it (to my understanding the purpose of the constraint layout is to remove the deep layout hierarchy).

Comment: will you add you constraintLayout blueprint to let me see buttons are in a relation with what ?

Comment: I added the blueprint of the ConstraintLayout with b3 selected

Answer (score 18):

You can easily convert any layout to a `ConstraintLayout`, just follow these directions:

1. Go to the design tab inside the layout editor of Android Studio
2. Open the Component Tree
3. Right click the LinearLayout (or other layout) you want to convert
4. Click on "Convert LinearLayout to ConstraintLayout"

[image]

Comment: I know, but the problem is that it does not behave correctly when you change the visibility of the buttons to "GONE".

Comment: @Hanan visibility behaves is different in ConstraintLayout

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never ever seen this conversion tool to be successful, even in seemingly simple layouts.

Comment: I have a `RelativeLayout` with 5 `TextView`. After conversion there was a `Missing Constraints in ConstraintLayout` error on every `TextView`.  Yeah, just click the `Convert to ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably change your layout to something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B1"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/b3"
        tools:layout_constraintBaseline_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B2"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="128dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="128dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="128dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="128dp"
        android:text="B3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B4"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/b3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/b3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBaseline_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you are having a tough time switching an existing layout to `ConstraintLayout`, you can go ahead and try out Android Studio's internal design tools to help you with it. You can switch to *Design* tab and open up *Component Tree* window, right click on the element you want to convert and select *Convert to ConstraintLayout*.

Comment: This looks OK when B2 is gone, but if I hide a different button it is not working OK. I assume that it was not clear (I will update the question as well), but programmatically I change the visibility of the buttons according to the app state.

Comment: Trying to use the AndroidStudio convert tools did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per this android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-chain), You can use Weighted Chains for this functionality.

For anyone still looking for a solution, I guess.