# How do I convert this Layout to ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to convert this layout to `ConstrainLayout` ,relativeLayout1 `layout_height` must be 60dp,how do I convert this layout to `ConstraintLayout`?

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate you must be looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41411721/convert-linearlayout-to-constraintlayout-issue

Comment: What is the purpose of the empty RelativeLayout? You just want to constrain the text views to the left half, or is that a placeholder for some other view that would go there?

Comment: @Tyler V It's the same as the one above, I just wanted to minimize the code in the question

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.74" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textview2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This is simple conversion of your above layout

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible conversion. Here are a few notes about this conversion:

- Setting the size of the ImageView to 60dp then constraining things to that effectively sets the height of the "row" to 60dp. If the text in the text views is long (or large font) it can still overflow the row. That was true with the relative layout too.
- Setting the vertical chain style for text views 2 and 3 to "packed" mimics what the internal linear layout does. If you just want them to be aligned to the top of the image then the chain is not necessary.

[image: Converted layout]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```